# What is the cost of electricity generated in the E175-E1?

Tags: turbofan, electrical-system, airlines, cost, embraer-e-jet

I'm comparing two types of cabin illumination, and I'm having a difficult time to estimate the cost that will be saved by utilizing lights with a lower power consumption.

What are the costs of electricity on board an airplane? Basically, I am looking for the cost of a kWh of electrical power generated by the engine, during an average travel of about two hours.

I edit to any kind of airplane, because some aircraft are easy to find data. Some information I found already:

- In round numbers, a 737 will burn 5,000 pounds (750 gallons) an hour. (https://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/columnist/cox/2014/10/12/boeing-737/17036931/)
- An A320's two alternators can produce 150 kilowatts (kW) and needs only 50 kW in total. (https://www.safran-electrical-power.com/media/20151109_more-electric-aircraft-how-does-electricity-work-plane)
- The cost of fuel is approximately $1/gallon (https://www.airlines.org/argus-us-jet-fuel-index/)

If somebody have any idea, I would be very grateful.

Comment: PSFC of typical turbo shaft is about a little less than pound per kWh.

Comment: Do you assume that the engine is running for no purpose other than turning the generator? So the entire cost of the fuel burned is divided into the electricity produced? Or should some of that cost be accounted to things like, moving people over long distances at high speeds?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I edited the question with more information.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking at the fractional cost of running the engine over a 2 hour flight. One fraction, very large, is for generating the thrust necessary to keep the plane in the air and moving toward its destination, another fraction is for bleed air to run the PAKS to keep the cabin comfortable, and another fraction is to generate electricity to run all the on-board electronics. It's this 3rd fraction that you're interested in, particularly the cost to run the cabin lights, not the avionics, radios, etc. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you assume costs are accounted in extra fuel burnt for electric generation (i.e. a quantity of fuel)?

Comment: I edited to any kind of aircraft and some informations I found. That's exactly it. If I have an approximately number of the cost of the fuel for each day in normal operation, what is the percentage that can be used in the ilumination? What would be the cost of the kWh? Thank you all in advance.